# Adding amounts present in the character format

Tags: jcl, dfsort

I have a PS with LRECL = 500 and RECFM=FB and in positions 70 through 82, I have the below amount fields in character format.

```
  -000000042.99
  -000000001.50
  -000000003.00
  -000000001.50
  -000000042.99
  +000000025.00
  +000000019.52
  +000000058.36
```

How can I convert this to Packed Decimal? My intention is I need to sum up the amounts field.Any ideas?

We have DFSORT. These amount fields are not in Packed decimal or numeric format. This file comes from an external system and I would like to sum all the amounts in this file through a JCL. I have to know the amount. For obvious reasons I do not wish to export this file to an excel and find the total there. I do not want to sum the totals based on a key. I just want to sum all the amounts in that file in that column.

Comment: Have a look at the Sort utility. Have a look at http://mainframe-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/sort-data-type-conversion.html this is not quite what you want but it should give you an idea of where to start

Comment: @BruceMartin that link is a bit spammy and the code there is shoddy. I don't think OP is interested in coming back anyway, as they've not shown up since seven hours after asking.

Comment: Again you should Accept the Answer that was most helpful to you if you get to a solution. Keeps us happy and willing to consider the next one :-)

Comment: Also note that you now have enough reputation to Vote on Questions and Answers. Answers don't have to be on your questions, if you see something helpful to you, or that you just like, you can Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
//SORTA    EXEC PGM=SORT                             
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                               
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                               
//SYSIN    DD  *                                     
  OPTION COPY                                        
   OUTFIL  REMOVECC,                                 
            TRAILER1=(TOTAL=(1,13,SFF,               
                              EDIT=(SIIIIIIIIT.TT),  
                              SIGNS=(+,-),           
                              LENGTH=13))            
//SORTIN   DD *                                      
-000000010.10                                        
-000000020.20                                        
+000000005.88                                        

Now I am getting the desired output
-000000010.10 
-000000020.20 
+000000005.88 
       -24.42
```

Comment: Thank you Bill Woodger, Based on your answer, I tried few times and was going through the link you provided me and now I am getting the desired output

Comment: OK. Got it. You were correct that the SFF was needed. The FS/CSF don't like decimal points (SFF and UFF don't mind, as they ignore all non-numerics). Updated my answer with a description.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple task using OUTFIL and its reporting functions:

```
//TOTALREP EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  OUTFIL  REMOVECC, 
          TRAILER1=(TOTAL=(1,13,SFF, 
                            EDIT=(SIIIIIIIIT.TT), 
                            SIGNS=(+,-), 
                            LENGTH=13)) 
//SORTIN   DD * 
-000000042.99 
-000000001.50 
-000000003.00 
-000000001.50 
-000000042.99 
+000000025.00 
+000000019.52 
+000000058.36
```

SORTOUT contains:

```
-000000042.99
-000000001.50
-000000003.00
-000000001.50
-000000042.99
+000000025.00
+000000019.52
+000000058.36
        +3.86
```

REMOVECC says don't include a printer Control Code, TRAILER1 is actioned at the end of the OUTFIL group, TOTAL (or TOT) says give a total of the position (here 1) length (13) and type (FS) (which you should look up in the DFSORT Application Programming Guide, which, for your version of DFSORT, can be found here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T7000080 . The EDIT, SIGNS and LENGTH dictate how the TOTAL value is going to appear.

UFF is Unsighed Free Format - This will strip out all non-numeric digits and process the result

SFF is Signed Free Format - This will strip out all non-numeric digits and process the result based on the presence, anywhere in the field, and that means anywhere, of one or more `-`If `-` is located, value will be negative otherwise positive.

FS
CSF These two are synonymous and can handle leading signs, but not decimal points. In the original example, the presence of the decimal point caused the number to be treated as only the decimal part. Everything in front of the decimal point was ignored, including the sign.

Comment: Dear Bill Woodger, Thank you for your time, your response resolved my problem. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Bill, Can you try adding values like +90.20 and 20.10? My output is coming like this.

Comment: +000000020.10  
+000000090.20  
        +0.30

Comment: Update your question (use edit link under the question) with your input data, the SORT control cards you are using, and the output you are getting.

Comment: Very good explanation on the UFF, FS and CSF. Thank you, good learning for me.

Comment: I have posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495215/date-format-in-trailer.

Comment: Can you please try to answer that as well?